# Nautilus Can't See Samba Shares

Tags: nautilus, samba, file-sharing

I have a Samba share set up on a Raspberry Pi that I connect to from my Ubuntu 16.04 PC. When I first set it up, Nautilus would discover it just fine in the Network section. For a while now, the only thing that shows up in "Network" is "Windows Network" which has "WORKGROUP" which will not open.

I can still connect and use the Samba share if I connect via smb://.

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 on my sister's laptop, and her laptop can't see the share either. However, all of the Windows PCs can see the networked folder just fine.

How do I fix this? I notice the program "gvfsd-smb-browse" using 100% CPU when I click the Network tab in Nautilus. Does this have something to do with it?